# Why do I have to use .self to reference the type object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am configuring a collection view to use my own custom cell however, I always wondered why I have to include .self on my cell class inside of the collectionview.register(any class, forCellReuseIdentifier).

Maybe my OOP skills are just lacking here, but why would .self reference the type object? Why does it need to know the type? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        //collectionView.register(FollowerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FollowerCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.register(FollowerCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: FollowerCell.reuseID)
    }
```

```
class FollowerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseID = "FollowerCell"
    
    let avatarImageView = GFAvatarImageView(frame: .zero)
    let userNameLabel = GFTitleLabel(textAlignment: .center, fontSize: 16)
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Ben-G/cb1708b1068d2bc5916f

Answer (score 5):

That's just the way Swift works. When you are asked to pass a *type* as a parameter, you cannot pass the bare name of the type; you pass the name plus `.self`.

You just have to accept that that's how the language works. It's like why is the French word for "yes", "oui"; you don't ask why, you just learn it and use it. Or why is a boundary hit 4 runs in cricket; you don't ask why, those are just the rules of the game.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I guess I am just a little bit confused on why they are asking for a type when it specifically just asks for the class. My newbie brain just thinks "oh, they want my cells class and that is it". But I guess a class is a named type, and each cell needs to know what type to be? Is this kinda correct? Thanks!

Comment: You are telling the table view what class of cell it should instantiate when a new cell is needed. So it is asking “what class?”  Your answer must therefore be in the form `ClassName.self`.